# get set property always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am declaring a Property - when I work on my dev environment it works fine BUT when i access the staging environment, it always returns null. Why is this happening? The code never changes in both environment. This is the code.

```
private ProductCollection _productCollection;    

public ProductCollection ProdCollection
{
    get
    {
        _productCollection = MWProductReviewHelper.GetDistinctProductFromTill(StoreId, TDPId, ReceiptId);
        if (_productCollection.Count > 0)
            return _productCollection;
        else
            return null;
    }
}

private ProductCollection _guaranteedProductCollection = new ProductCollection();

public ProductCollection GuaranteedProductCollections
{
    get
    {
        if (_guaranteedProductCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            return _guaranteedProductCollection;
        }
        else
        {
            return _guaranteedProductCollection = MWProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection);  // the problem appears to be here... 
        }
    }
}
```

I access is like this.

```
if (GuaranteedProductCollections.Count > 0)
{
    ProductCollection _prodCollection = GuaranteedProductCollections; // return null
}
```

It always has one product inside it - I can see this when I put in a breakpoint.

Comment: if `GuaranteedProductCollections` returns null then this line `if (GuaranteedProductCollections.Count > 0)` will throw `NullReferenceException`. Are you sure `GetDistinctProductFromTill` method returns some values?

Comment: `CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList` returns null. This might be because `ProdCollection` is null...and this might be because `GetDistinctProductFromTill` returns empty collection.

Comment: GetDistinctProductFromTill() returns values. i can see it while debugging...

Comment: I assumed this values are form database? Are data in database in production enviroment?

Comment: yes. it uses the same database on dev as well as on staging ...

Comment: it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on return _guaranteedProductCollection = MWProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection) this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to bump that set on two lines?  Looks like it might be returning before the set is complete.

```
public ProductCollection GuaranteedProductCollections
      {
        get
          {
            if (_guaranteedProductCollection.Count > 0)
              {
                 return _guaranteedProductCollection;
              }
            else
              {
                _guaranteedProductCollection = MWProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection);  // the problem appears to be here... 
                return _guaranteedProductCollection;
              }
           }
      }
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying. BUT i can assure that it ProductCollection Property returns values. AND it is working fine on my DEV machine. when i put it on server, it fails and returns null

Comment: @patel.milanb on your dev machine are you building in Release or Debug mode?  If you build in Release mode, do you see the problem?

Comment: on DEV its in release mode.. still problem

Answer (score 1):

If your `GuaranteedProductCollections` property is returning null then it must be either because:

- `MWProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection)` is returning null.
- Something else is setting `_guaranteedProductCollection` to be null (this is unlikely as `_guaranteedProductCollection` is not null when testing its count, as this would throw an exception)

As an aside, generally when initialising collections in this way its best to use `null` to represent an uninitialised collection to allow for the case where your collection is initialised, however is empty.  I'd implement your property like this:

```
public ProductCollection GuaranteedProductCollections
{
    get
    {
        if (_guaranteedProductCollection == null)
        {
            _guaranteedProductCollection = WProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection);
        }
        return _guaranteedProductCollection;
    }
}
```

This can be simplified to 1 line with [null-coalescing (??) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
public ProductCollection GuaranteedProductCollections
{
    get
    {
        return _guaranteedProductCollection
            ?? _guaranteedProductCollection = WProductGuaranteedHelper.CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try this. CheckGuaranteedProductsFromList(ProdCollection) is a static method. do you think that has to do anything with this error

Comment: @patel.milanb From what I can see the most likely explanation is that this method is returning null.

Comment: i am preety sure that it returns values and both environment uses the same database